# PHP SQL Error Resource #6

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
//Connect to config file
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");
//Connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect("$dbHost", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die ("Error connecting to database.");
mysql_select_db("$dbDatabase", $db) or die ("Couldn't select the database.");

//Get Total Products
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat'");
$TotalProducts = mysql_num_rows($result);

//Create Pages
if (TotalProducts <= 12){
    $pages = '';
}else{
    $pages = "                  <ul id=\"pagination\" class=\"group\">
                        <li><a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"#\">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"#\">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"#\">4</a></li>
                    </ul>";
}




//Get from sql info we need
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat' LIMIT 0 , 12");
$data = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//Make first letter UpperCase
$subcatname = ucfirst($subcat);
//Get Basket Count
$basketcount = count($_COOKIE['products']);

//Get All Products
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
//Get Product Path
$productPath = $Domain.'/'.strtolower($row['category']).'/'.str_replace(" ","",$row['product_name']).'_'.$row['product_id'];

//Build Products List
$products = $products."     <li class=\"all-products-list-item\">
            <a href=\"$productPath\" title=\"{$row['product_name']}\"><img src=\"$ProductImageFolder{$row['thumb_image']}\" alt=\"{$row['product_name']}\" border=\"0\" height=\"245\" width=\"180\"/></a>
            <h3><a href=\"$productPath\">{$row['product_name']}</a></h3>
            <p>£{$row['price']}</p>
        </li>\n";
}
```

and here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #6' at line 1
```

i have tried running it throught phpmyadmin and the sql works perfect, i cant find what the problem is ?

Thanks

Comment: what about $subcat? where is declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
//Get from sql info we need
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat' LIMIT 0 , 12");
$data = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Change it to

```
//Get from sql info we need
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat' LIMIT 0 , 12";
$data = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

You are running a query with `$sql = mysql_query(...)`, and are assigning the resource to the variable `$sql`. Right after that, you try to run a query with the variable `$sql` as a parameter. At this point `$sql` will contain the resource, not the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat'");
```

replace this with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat'";
var_dump($sql);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

think this helps

**EDIT:**

what for to do this:

```
$db = mysql_connect("$dbHost", "$dbUser", "$dbPass");
```

write like this:

```
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT * FROM $dbProductsTable

PHP sees a PHP variable here and is substituting the value for it (in this case $db)

SQL entity identifiers should follow naming conventions - a naming convention that allows table names to start with anything other than a letter is a bad idea, they should only contain letters and digits.

Try:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `\$dbProductsTable` 
     WHERE sub_cat = '$subcat' LIMIT 0 , 12");
```